# Material3 ModalBottomSheet How to set fullscreen background image

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material3, modalbottomsheet

I am trying to implement a `ModalBottomSheet` with `Material3`. Everything works like expected but I don't get colored the area which google called container. Or more precisely: I would like to have a background image.

I do not care if the `ModalBottomSheet` has the background image or the element inside.

I tried something like that

```
        ModalBottomSheet(
            sheetState = sheetState,
            content = {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.app_background),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize(),
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                    )
                }
            },
            onDismissRequest = {
                pressedBack.invoke()
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            tonalElevation = 20.dp,
        )
```

Does anybody know how I can manipulate this area? I cannot find anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: drag handle]

The area is called **drag handle**.

You can set that to null, like this:

```
    ModalBottomSheet(
    sheetState = sheetState,
    content = {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.app_background),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )
        }
    },
    onDismissRequest = {
        pressedBack.invoke()
    },
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    tonalElevation = 20.dp,
    dragHandle = null,
    //or set that to empty 
    // or any composables you want
    //dragHandle = {}
)
```